# twitter : getAuthenticateUrl : Object of class EpiTwitterJson could not be converted to string

Tags: php, json, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitter-async library

when I use getAuthenticateUrl() as

```
$authenticate_url = $twitter->getAuthenticateUrl();
```

on doing this:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo ($authenticate_url) ? "success".$authenticate_url : "error";
?>
```

I get this error

Object of class EpiTwitterJson could not be converted to string

I would be really grateful if you could please help me with this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `$authenticate_url` is an object which you can't echo as a string. Try `var_dump($authenticate_url);` to see what `$authenticate_url` is/contains.